# how to connect and share data between multiple nodejs servers?

Tags: node.js, express

i am using express framework, in my requirement have to maintain a login server and content server, a user can login from one server and then searching the content's from other server.

any best idea to implement this concept? and please share, how to share the user's data while connecting or redirecting to another server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creation sessions on logging, then you can session across multiple node process/servers using extenal session store service.

Search on Express session stores.

You can store session on mongodb/redis or any other.

Redis Session Store example : http://blog.arisetyo.com/?p=492

Comment: thanks for your reply!... as per your knowledge am storing my session in mongo db and how can i process that session in other server. for example: i am login through one server and my session is stored in db and if want to display my username in other server how can i get it ?

Comment: Since you're using the same database at both servers, you can retrieve any data regardless of where it was saved. This means, you should just perform a proper `db.find` query at the content server, because you've already saved the session information at the login server.

Comment: if not maintaining session, sending information through socket is enough?